# C3P0 connection pooling with hibernate doesnt work with cloudfoundry

Tags: spring, hibernate, cloud-foundry

I am trying to push a simple hibernate+MYSQL app developed using STS. Hibernate uses c3P0 for connection pooling. When I push the app and start accessing it I see exceptions related to c3P0.I tested it locally and it works well.

> ```
> Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A
> ```
>
> ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or
>   source.
>         at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
>         at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
>         at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
>         at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)

This is the cloud profile I am using.

```
 <beans profile="cloud">
         <bean id="c3p0DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${cloud.services.mysql.connection.jdbcUrl}" />
            <property name="user" value="${cloud.services.mysql.connection.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${cloud.services.mysql.connection.password}" />
            <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
            <property name="maxPoolSize" value="3" />
            <property name="maxIdleTime" value="20" />
        </bean>
          <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="c3p0DataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop> 
      <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
      <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
    </props>
      </property>
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.iml.policytype.model" /> 
       </bean>
      <tx:annotation-driven /> 
     <context:component-scan base-package="com.iml.policytype.bo" /> 
     <context:component-scan base-package="com.iml.policytype.dao" />
 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
</beans>
```

Can anyone help?

here is the exception

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:514)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.getPolicyType(Unknown Source)
    at com.symantec.netbackup.iml.webservice.PolicyTypeResource.getMsg(PolicyTypeResource.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:680)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:550)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:428)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    ... 54 more
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the `hibernate.connection.provider_class` as you are injecting a datasource. Next to that you are configuring hibernate with a reference to `devnexus-db` whereas you have a bean named `c3p0DataSource`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion ..I had changed it already but still its not working, I also reduced connection pool size to less than 5 as I heard cleadb mysql allows max 10 connections.. BUt it is still not working.

Comment: Post the full stacktrace and please update the code to what you currently have..

Comment: Between I came to know that jdbc url should have the value cloud.services.mysql.connection.jdbcUrl. So I did this change. Cleardb mysql doesnt allow connections more than 10 so changed the pool size also. Between anyone knows how to make sure that db is properly up and running... I see that in the pivotal console that its up and running but if I try to connect it using credentials it gives error ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'us-cdbr-east-04.cleardb.com' (10061)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work with though I didn't try with profile stuff

Following is the xml that should be used if you want to use c3P0.

```
        <cloud:data-source id="c3p0DataSource" service-name="mysql"/>
         <cloud:properties id="cloudProperties"/>
         <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="cloudProperties"/>

<bean id="c3p0DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://${cloud.services.mysql.connection.hostname}:${cloud.services.mysql.connection.port}/${cloud.services.mysql.connection.name}" />

            <property name="user" value="${cloud.services.mysql.connection.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${cloud.services.mysql.connection.password}" />
            <property name="minPoolSize" value="2" />
            <property name="maxPoolSize" value="3" />
            <property name="maxIdleTime" value="319" />

        </bean>
        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="c3p0DataSource" />

            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>


                </props>
            </property>
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.iml.policytype.model" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
            p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
```

I didnt use variable {cloud.services.mysql.connection.jdbcUrl} which was causing the DB connection to fail. If you observe the env.log file the value for this entry also contains username and password instead of just hostname, portname and db name.

Also the property cloud.services.mysql.connection.hostname I have seen mentioned as (cloud.services.mysql.connection.name) that was also causing the issue. I guess that's not a big deal as it depends on which data source you use. In some cases it could be name and in some cases it could be hostname.

Also the highlighted code was missing entries from my xml. I would be trying now with profile feature  and would update the thread based on what I see.